# Self-signed Certificate - Unable to connect using ANT Build

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, exception, ant

I'm trying to connect to all the links in a particular webpage and get the response to see if the link is broken.

Some of the links are SSL that too self-certified.
So, I've followed the procedure of adding the certificate to trust store. After that it worked fine, when I tested the same in Eclipse(it returned OK/200).

But, when I build and run the project using ANT in command line, the same exception appears.
And it is weird that it doesn't happen when I build using the same xml through Eclipse; it simply works!

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Do you have multiple Java versions installed? Ant will take the JAVA_HOME version if none is explicitely configured. If you have configured Eclipse to use a different version this would explain why it works with Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I've both 7 & 8 installed. JAVA_HOME is configured to 8, and Eclipse is also using 8. What would be the best option for me now?

Comment: By the way, I've generated the jssecacerts file using 7 and added it to both 7 and 8 security directory. Will that be causing this issue? I've run the same ANT build in both 7 and 8 using Eclipse, and it works every-time. But using ANT in command-line, it doesn't. I've no idea why this is happening. Hours of frustration!

Comment: Just figured out that both ANT is also using 8. But for some reason it is not accepting the certificate file added to the security directory. Any help on trying to narrow down the problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, Java also installs a separate JRE alongside the JDK, so make sure that the certificate is actually inserted into jre\lib\security\cacerts and jdk1.x.0_xx\jre\lib\security\cacerts.

Comment: @dudel : You saved my day. Thank you so much! Inserting the certificate in the jdk1.x.0_xx\jre\lib\security solved the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I will add an answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my previous comments Java installs a JRE alongside the JDK which in turn also has a JRE installed. Thus if you are not sure which one is used you can try to add the certificate into jre\lib\security\cacerts and jdk1.x.0_xx\jre\lib\security\cacerts.