# Secure connection via Ant

Tags: java, ssl, https, ant

The requirement is to connect to a secure connection in Ant.

```
<condition property="application.state" else="false">
    <http url="${agentUrl}" />
</condition>
```

What would be the way to use 'https' in place of 'http' or some other way to use the secure connection. Below is the code snippet I found in internet for producing the key. But not sure how it could be used in above scenario.

```
<genkey alias="${verisign.key.alias}" verbose="true"
storepass="${verisign.key.storepass}" keypass="${verisign.key.pass}"
validity="365" keystore="${verisign.key.store}">
    ...
</genkey>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The *condition* task will connect to a remote URL and set the condition upon success of failure (see: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#http). Why do you need to create a keystore using the *genkey* task?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I am trying to connect to a https url in place of http. To connect to this https url I will need  to link it with a certificate chain. What could be the way to link local certificates to this https url and receive response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154044/self-signed-certificate-unable-to-connect-using-ant-build